# Links starting with double slashes cause invalid requests

Tags: .htaccess, request

All links on my website are protocol-less and start with double slashes:
href="//site.com/page.html".

And in the log I see many requests like: 404 - site.com/site.com/page.html

Which means some browsers are interpreting these absolute links as relative. By looking at the user agents I assume those are mostly bots.

Can I fix requests such as site.com/site.com/page.html with .htaccess by directing them to the proper URI? (site.com/site.com/page.html => site.com/page.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your document root (of the site that's hosting these protocol relative links):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site.com/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1
```

or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site.com/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If the site that is hosting these links is already **site.com**, you can remove the `http://site.com` bit from the targets.